# Trying to print the pixel values of 32bit floating point image

Tags: c, opencv

I am trying to print pixel intensities of 32bit floating point image.  And here is the code that I am using.  Thre are two types of values in the image, by seeing it in imread on matlab, NAN and floating points.  The program loads the image but it hangs when tried running.  Can anyone suggest me what went wrong.  Thanks for your help.

```
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>

void printIplImage(const IplImage* src)
{
    int row = 0,col = 0;
    for(row = 0; row < src->height; row++)
    {
        for(col = 0; col < src->width; col++)
        {       
            printf("%f, ", ((float*)(src->imageData + src->widthStep*row))[col]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    IplImage *t3 = cvLoadImage("divimages1.tiff",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);

    printIplImage(t3);

    cvReleaseImage (&t3);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure the image data is loaded as 32-bit float? Try [converting it explicitly as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6349493/163956)

Comment: Actually, I would suspect the `cvLoadImage()`call. OpenCV relies on the underlying `libtiff` to read the file, and there is no indication here of the OS. Hence, directly reading a 32-bits tiff file to an `IplImage` is maybe just not supported.

Comment: Well I had wirte a code on tiff library and use that.  SO anyone having problems with 32 bit tiff image, using the tiff library it.Sincethe best option, since opencv still dont support 32bit.

Answer (score 0):

It would be good if you check the datatype of your loaded image first. Below is the code which can help you to know the datatype. And if is not in "float" format then ***first of all extract the value of pixel in its own format and then do the typecast later***. I have also faced the similar problem earlier and it helped me.

Here is a handy function you can use to help with identifying your opencv matrices at runtime. I find it useful for debugging, at least.

```
string type2str(int type) {
  string r;

  uchar depth = type & CV_MAT_DEPTH_MASK;
  uchar chans = 1 + (type >> CV_CN_SHIFT);

  switch ( depth ) {
    case CV_8U:  r = "8U"; break;
    case CV_8S:  r = "8S"; break;
    case CV_16U: r = "16U"; break;
    case CV_16S: r = "16S"; break;
    case CV_32S: r = "32S"; break;
    case CV_32F: r = "32F"; break;
    case CV_64F: r = "64F"; break;
    default:     r = "User"; break;
  }

  r += "C";
  r += (chans+'0');

  return r;
}
```

If `M` is a var of type `Mat` you can call it like so:

```
string ty =  type2str( M.type() );
printf("Matrix: %s %dx%d \n", ty.c_str(), M.cols, M.rows );
```

Will output data such as:

```
Matrix: 8UC3 640x480 
Matrix: 64FC1 3x2
```